# Dimensional array items are not inserting in the same DB row

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I start with the following:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
 <?php foreach($attributes as $attribute){ ?>
  <input type="checkbox" name="attribute[][attr_id]" value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="attribute[][attr_name]"> value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_name']; ?>">
 <?php } ?>
</form>
```

So each $attribute has a checkbox and a text input; whenever someone would check (one or more boxes) and would insert text (only to the checked items) I want to get in the DB the `[attr_id]` and the `[attr_name]` for the specific item.

So I continue with the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['attribute'])){
 foreach($_POST['attribute'] as $attribute){
    $attr_id = $attribute['attr_id'];
    $attr_name = $attribute['attr_name'];

    "INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "attribute_xref SET productid = '" . $productid . "', attribute_id='". $attr_id ."', attribute_name='" . $attr_name . "'";
  }
 }
```

But, the result is a little different as of I would have expected. Every time a box is checked and its text input is typed, their values are sent to two different DB rows:

```
productid   --   attribute_id   --   attribute_name
10          --       102        --        empty
10          --        0         --       somename
```

On the above second row the attribute_id has zero value for not being checked.

I cannot get the whole picture where is my mistake.

Comment: Not 100% about the main issue, I would guess that the php foreach loop is picking up each input individually, but you should *really* look into parametrized queries. Concatenating the SQL together like that is a horrible security risk - look up "SQL Injection" for more info.

Comment: The form is used only by team users on an administration panel, that's why I have a non parametrized querie, but of course it is not a proffesionist manner.

Comment: And yes, I see that the two inputs have different array keys. So I guess I am using the wrong method for the desired result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. The tricky answer was to add an identical numerical index to the associative inputs like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
  <?php foreach($attributes as $attribute){ ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="attribute[i][attr_id]" value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="attribute[i][attr_name]"> value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_name']; ?>">
  <?php } ?>
</form>
```

where "i" in my case would take the variable number from 'attribute_id':

```
<input type="checkbox" name="attribute[<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>][attr_id]" value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="attribute[<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>][attr_name]"> value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_name']; ?>">
```

Hopefully my answer would help somebody in the future, too.